# Installing express on vagrant

Tags: node.js, express, virtual-machine, vagrant

Im trying to get an express app to work on with vagrant, but it i keep getting an error

```
npm ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: <any package>
```

i would like to install nodejs and npm without having to use any "pre-made bundles", if that makes sense.

i have tried using `sudo apt-get nodejs` but it installs version 0.6.4 of node which is not the latest.

i've also tried installing without the command `--no-bin-links` but i still get the same `npm ERR!`

any clue?.

Comment: did you try `sudo apt-get update` first?

Comment: yes, thats the first thing i did.

Comment: can you try `sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy` and see which version that installs?

Comment: Which OS/version are you using? And, can you reach an outside host from your Vagrant host?

Comment: try `npm install express --no-bin-links` .